# Is there any side effect of increasing file_cache_size_in_mb?

Tags: cassandra

I use cassandra 3.9, but `outOfMemoryError` happens often and each nodes has been down one by one.
I'm making a research about configuration, and I think one of the way is to increase `file_cache_size_in_mb`. Current size is 512MB.
But I'm not an expert of memory usage, and anxious about side effect to performance. I think disk cache will be cut off and cassandra's I/O performance is slowed down a little.
Do you know any other points I should be aware?

My machine spec is:

- machine memory is 128GB. Java heap is 8GB.
- Right now only 18GB is used, but another 100GB is allocated for OS disk cache. Totally free memory is about 1GB.
- No other process except cassandra.

Comment: have `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` on? Can you use jmap to look at heap histogram? Whats taking up space. 8gb is minimal size, on 128gb system give it at least 16gb, any higher and be sure to use G1 though. If your on SSDs give even more to heap as disk probably isnt your bottleneck. Need more info (`nodetool info/tablestats/tablehistograms` and heap histogram) to help though - very doubtful that `file_cache_size_in_mb` will help or impact it at all.

Comment: Interesting to know the tradeoff between OS disk cache and Cass Cache